# How to write a greek word bold in beamer in Latex?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, bold, greek

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Luebeck}
}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\providecommand{\myceil}[1]{\left \lfloor #1 \right \rfloor }

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\title[Βέλτιστοι Πειραματικοί Σχεδιασμοί]{Βέλτιστοι Πειραματικοί Σχεδιασμοί 
με Παράγοντες σε δύο και περισσότερα Επίπεδα} % The short title appears at 
the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{Χασιώτης Α. Βασίλειος} % Your name
\institute[Α.Π.Θ.] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of 
every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης \\ % Your institution for the title   
page
\medskip
\textit{\textlatin{chasiotisv@math.auth.gr}} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{$2^k$ Μη Πλήρεις Παραγοντικοί Σχεδιασμοί Εκτιμητικής Τάξης ΙΙΙ}
\textbf{Θεώρημα}\\
\textbf{\textlatin{Moyssiadis \& Kounias}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:
[image]
[image]

The "Moyssiadis & Kounias" is getting bold, but the word "Θεώρημα" is not getting bold. I think that the problem is because the word "Θεώρημα" is in Greek. How to fix it?

If I use package package `tempora` instead of `newtxtext` I have the following errors:

```
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textChi'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomega'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\texttau'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\texteta'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textvarsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textAlpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textBeta'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textlambda'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomicron'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textvarsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textBeta'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textlambda'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\texttau'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\texttau'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomicron'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textPi'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textrho'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\texttau'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textkappa'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomicron'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textSigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textchi'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textdelta'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomicron'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textPi'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textrho'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textgamma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomicron'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textnu'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\texttau'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textvarsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textdelta'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textupsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomicron'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textkappa'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textpi'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textrho'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textsigma'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textomicron'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\texttau'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textrho'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textEpsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textpi'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\ensuregreek'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\acctonos'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textiota'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textpi'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textepsilon'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textdelta'
Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot seem to reproduce your problem. It compiles fine for me and the Greek is printed bold.

Comment: @JasperHabicht It works on me only if I delete the package `newtxtext`. But I need it because I want Times New Roman.

Comment: The picture you show can be reproduced if you put `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` last. The package`newtxtext` does not support Greek. You can use `tempora`instead: `\usepackage{tempora,newtxmath}`

Comment: If you want Times why do you load lmodern?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I do not, using the code given above, I have the following error: Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textChi`.

Comment: I don't get an error, but if I would get an error I wouldn't load a font package that overwrites the font I want to use. Show your log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will edit my question.

Comment: Better create a new one so that the answers here stay valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to PDFLaTex, you can use the `tempora` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{$2^k$ Μη Πλήρεις Παραγοντικοί Σχεδιασμοί Εκτιμητικής Τάξης ΙΙΙ}
  \textbf{Θεώρημα}\\
  \textbf{\textlatin{Moyssiadis \& Kounias}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT:** The OP provided more information concerning his problem. Hence, I edit my answer accordingly. This should not throw any warning:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Luebeck}
}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\hypersetup{unicode}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\providecommand{\myceil}[1]{\left \lfloor #1 \right \rfloor }

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\title[Βέλτιστοι Πειραματικοί Σχεδιασμοί]{Βέλτιστοι Πειραματικοί Σχεδιασμοί 
με Παράγοντες σε δύο και περισσότερα Επίπεδα} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{Χασιώτης Α. Βασίλειος} % Your name
\institute[Α.Π.Θ.] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης \\ % Your institution for the title   page
\medskip
\textit{\textlatin{chasiotisv@math.auth.gr}} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{$2^k$ Μη Πλήρεις Παραγοντικοί Σχεδιασμοί Εκτιμητικής Τάξης ΙΙΙ}
\textbf{Θεώρημα}\\
\textbf{\textlatin{Moyssiadis \& Kounias}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have the following error: Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textChi`. 

In this line I have the first greek which is X, that is `\Chi`.

Comment: Why do you need this command? You should write `$X$` instead, or just X (Chi) in plain text. BTW: I forgot to add `\usefonttheme{serif}` in my answer. Sorry.

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis See my edit: you should add `\hypersetup{unicode}` to your preamble.

Comment: I still having the same errors. I edited my question. Take a look.

Comment: Did you reorder the packages like I suggest in my answer? This may solve some problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72704/discussion-between-vassilis-chasiotis-and-jasper-habicht).

Answer (score 5):

Use `xelatex` or `lualatex`. TeX Gyre Termes is the free Times Roman

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\setromanfont{TeXGyreTermes-Regular}
\setsansfont{TeXGyreHeros-Regular}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{$2^k$ Μη Πλήρεις Παραγοντικοί Σχεδιασμοί Εκτιμητικής Τάξης ΙΙΙ}
\textbf{Θεώρημα}

\textbf{Moyssiadis \& Kounias}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work.

Comment: @VassilisChasiotis "Does not work" is not a very helpful statement.